# How to insert strftime with for loop in SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm created table with columns type 'date' in `SQLite`.
But, when i call insert statement with params:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [@"strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d at %%H:%%M','now', 'localtime')" UTF8String],  -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

It's not working and return result:

```
strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d at %%H:%%M','now', 'localtime')
```

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `sqlite3_bind_text` you are binding a literal string value. The string is not executed.

Let's assume you have something like this:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandle, "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)", -1, query, nil);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [@"strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d at %%H:%%M','now', 'localtime')" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "Other value", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

What you want in this case is something like this:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandle, "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d at %%H:%%M','now', 'localtime'), ?)", -1, query, nil);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "Other value", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

You want the `strftime` call directly in your query. Notice that since you have one less `?` in the query, you need to adjust the indexes used in the calls to `sqlite3_bind_xxx`.